# OpenACC and floor/ceil functions

Tags: c++, floor, openacc, ceil

I want to use floor/ceil functions of C in an OpenACC project. When I want to make an atomic update of a value.

```
#pragma acc atomic update
x=floor(x)+c
```

the compiler shows the following message:

PGCC-S-0155-Invalid atomic expression 
PGCC-S-0155-Invalid atomic region.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Atomic operations are for simple and straightforward operations like +, -, *, and /. If you take a look at the Section 2.12 (Atomic Construct) of the OpenACC Spec Page 42 [[link](http://www.openacc.org/sites/default/files/OpenACC_2pt5.pdf)], you will see the list of available operations to use in atomic construct.

So, although you could do `floor` on GPU, you cannot do it in *atomic* *sections*.